# TPTP client on Linux Machine

Tags: linux, windows, ftp, tftp

I am trying to copy a text file from a Linux Server to a Windows server 2008 Machine. I have setup a Trivial File Transfer (TFTP) server on the Windows machine. I would like to know if i need any TFTP client installed on the Linux server in order to copy the file over to the Windows machine?

Regards.

Answer (score 0):

While some Linux distributions have stand-alone TFTP clients built-in, most usually do not have TFTP installed as part of the standard installation. So yes, you will have to install the client manually.  Once you install the TFTP client you can do something like this:

```
tftp 192.168.1.100 
tftp> put somefile.txt
tftp> quit
```